# How it is correctly to implement IDTExtensibility2 interface for Office COM Add-In?

Tags: .net, outlook, office-interop, comaddin

I am implementing COM Add-In for Outlook. I use IDTExtensibility2. I am not sure whether this is the best way of doing COM Add-Ins but I cannot change that.

This interface defines five methods: OnConnection, OnStartupComplete, OnAddInsUpdate, OnBeginShutdown, OnDisconnection.

I need to perform the following operations:

1. Load configuration data from file
2. Load registry data
3. Start new session
4. Create *.pst file
5. Subscribe to Explorer events
6. Connect to Internet Server to get some data
7. Create menu items in the main menu
8. Create a toolbar
9. Add/Remove several things in Outllok (on *.pst files level)

Please advise, what I am supposed to do when?

- What I need to perform in OnConnection method?
- What is allowed only when OnStartupComplete invokes?
- What resources I need to free dispose during OnBeginShutdown / OnDisconnection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 1,2 and 6 are not Outlook-addin-specific tasks.

3 is not needed: As an addin you don't create a session - you get connected with an existing one (by implementing the `OnConnection` method).

For 4 and 9 I recommend using RDO: http://dimastr.com/redemption/
(can also be used for 3 if you really need another session)

For 5,7 and 8 I recommend using ADX: http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/
(you won't actually have to worry about `IDTExtensibility2` at all anymore if you do this)

`OnConnection` is where you grab your reference to the `Application` interface from which you can derive everything else.

`OnStartupComplete` is where you can put all your initialization code.

`OnDisconnection` is where you should release all remaining OOM references you may have accumulated during the session, i.e  everything that was derived from the initial `Application` reference that you received via `OnConnection`.

Comment: ..."I recommend using ADX: http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/"...
Sure - for $349