# _IDTExtensibility2, what DLL to import into ATL project?

Tags: c++, com, atl

So I'm trying to solve my [Office add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387277/how-it-is-correctly-to-implement-idtextensibility2-interface-for-office-com-add) task again; I have created the ATL project, added simple class, and now want to add interface implementation, as http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/Writing-an-MS-Word-Addin/1/ proposes;

However, available type libraries list has no listed Extensibility to add; I checked under Program Files, but the Extensibility.dll found there was a .NET assembly without exposed COM classes.
[image: available type libraries]

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Designer\MSADDNDR.olb.  That article is *seriously* outdated.  I'd strongly recommend getting started in C# and if necessary use C++/CLI to interop with C++ code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type library is `{AC0714F2-3D04-11D1-AE7D-00A0C90F26F4}`, named "Microsoft Add-In Designer" hosted by probably `MSADDNDR.DLL`.

```
// typelib filename: MSADDNDR.DLL

[
  uuid(AC0714F2-3D04-11D1-AE7D-00A0C90F26F4),
  version(1.0),
  helpstring("Microsoft Add-In Designer")
]
```

[image]