# No typelibs available in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, com

I am developing a native COM based (C++, ATL) addin for Microsoft Office using Visual Studio.

As I plan to upgrade from VS 2013 to VS 2019 I ran some tests and was not able to let a class implement IDTExtensibility2 through the class view as there are no typelibs available for me to select from the registry. I installed the workloads for MFC and ATL as well.

Maybe someone is experienced and can give me a hint whats missing. With VS 2013 I do not experience the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947227/idtextensibility2-what-dll-to-import-into-atl-project

Comment: @HansPassant the Problem is, that this drop-down menu is empty in VS 2019! And I don't know why. That is the topic of the question.

Comment: It is not so obvious that you're using that *dialog* correctly.  Select File.